# Is it safe to generate an email subject from the body?

Tags: email

I'm writing an app which allows users to send out a text-only email to a bunch of recipients. I want to try and generate the subject of this email from the body of the message, to avoid the need for a subject field

Is it safe enough to do this? Are these emails likely to fall foul of spam filters?

I'm already scanning the entire email for spam words, so there won't be any in the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could download the widely used spamfilter [Spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) and search for 'SUBJ' in the *.cf files, this will give you many spamrules that trigger based on subject  (like empty subject, all caps, bad words, bad encoding of non-ascii characters etc)

Comment: thanks, I downloaded it before but I wasn't sure where to look!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if the mail is from a trusted source then there is not a problem. On the other hand since the mailbox dosent know that the subject is generated automatically it does not matter to them. And the third thing is that you need to check the guidelines that the email filters follow. Check out some ope source mail filter.